# Change xaml bound ObservableCollection<type>'s, type at runtime UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a `DataGrid` in my xaml page that I bind to an `ObservableCollection` "MainListData", in the page's viewModel, using MVVM:

```
    <controls:DataGrid Grid.Column="1"
                       Background="Gray"
                       ItemsSource="{Binding MainListData}"
                       AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                       GridLinesVisibility="All"
                       AlternatingRowBackground="LightGray">
    </controls:DataGrid>
```

I want to use the `ObservableCollection` to show various types of datasets. `DataGrid` works nicely with it's `AutoGenerateColumns`, using the custom `<type>` in `ObservableCollection<type>`.
 For instance, `ObservableCollection<Cars>`:

```
public class Cars
{
    public string Sedans { get; set; }
    public string Pickup { get; set; }
    public string Unknown { get; set; }
}
```

will show as:

```
+--------+---------+--------+
| Sedans | Pickup  | Uknown |
+--------+---------+--------+
| car 1  | pickup1 | ?1     |
| car 2  | pickup2 | ?2     |
| ...    | ...     | ...    |
+--------+---------+--------+
```

**OR**, `ObservableCollection<Bikes>`:

```
public class Bikes
{
    public string Fast { get; set; }
    public string Slow { get; set; }
    public string Big { get; set; }
    public string Small { get; set; }
    public string Electric { get; set; }
}
```

will show as:

```
+--------+-------+------+--------+-----------+
|  Fast  | Slow  | Big  | Small  | Electric  |
+--------+-------+------+--------+-----------+
| fast 1 | slow1 | big1 | small1 | electric1 |
| fast 2 | slow2 | big2 | small2 | electric2 |
| ...    | ...   | ...  | ...    | ...       |
+--------+-------+------+--------+-----------+
```

**Question:** At runtime: if the user selects to see the data of Cars or Bikes or other data, how can I change the `<type>` and thus data of the bound "MainListData" `ObservableCollection`? Is this the correct approach?

I presume I want to re-use the `DataGrid` and bound `ObservableCollection`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the document of [DataGrid](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-CN/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid_guidance/datagrid_basics#binding-a-datagrid-to-a-data-source), it mentions when you set the ItemsSource property and ItemsSource, the DataGrid control generates columns automatically. So if you want to swtich between the Cars and Bikes data, just need to re-set the ItemsSource, it will re-generate columns. For example:

.xaml:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Click="Button_Click">change to Bikes</Button>

    <controls:DataGrid Grid.Column="1"
                       Background="Gray"
                       ItemsSource="{x:Bind MainListData,Mode=OneWay}"
                       AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                       AlternatingRowBackground="LightGray" x:Name="MyDataGrid">

    </controls:DataGrid>
</StackPanel>
```

.cs:

```
private ObservableCollection<Bikes> MainListData2 { get; set; }

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = MainListData2;
}
```

Comment: I use MVVM and thus a viewModel. Therefore no code-behind of the page.xaml.cs to set it's itemsource in code. Which I take what you are suggesting above?

Comment: Do you mean you don't have the page.xaml.cs file in your project? Can you provide a simple sample for us to test?

Comment: I "retain" the page.xaml.cs, but do not use it at all, since I use MVVM...
I don't believe a sample is necessary, since this is a question in theory or "semantics"- what can you do within the rules of C#.  I got to a solution as an example, I will, unfortunately answer my own question now

Answer (score 0):

FYI - I hate to answer my own questions, and will not choose it as the accepted answer until someone here agrees that it is a good, or an adequate and proper solution to my question:

I changed the object bound to the xaml `DataGrid`, from an `ObservableCollection` to an `object`:

```
    private object MainListData_;
    public object MainListData
    {
        get { return MainListData_; }
        set { SetProperty(ref MainListData_, value); }
    }
```

Then, you set that object equal to any `List<type>` as your user so selects, for instance:

```
        List<UserDetails> userDetails = new List<UserDetails>();

        userDetails.Add(new UserDetails { Info = "UserName"() });
        userDetails.Add(new UserDetails { Info = "UserPC"});
        userDetails.Add(new UserDetails { Info = "UserID"});

        MainListData = userDetails;
```

This successfully updates the DataGrid with columns and data specific to your `List<type>`, which can have any custom `Type` you instantiate a `List` with. Thus, bypassing the problem of trying to "`ReDim`" an `ObservableCollection` at runtime.